# OnTouchListener receives oscilating touch points

Tags: android, view, ontouchlistener

I have an activity where i set an OnTouchListener to a View (see code below). It should translate the View horizontally a bit until the GestureDetector kicks in and does something.

The code so far is very simple ignoring multiple touch events etc... I will include this later.

```
getView().setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    private float downPos = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View vw, MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                downPos = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d("MyActivity", "X: " + event.getX());
                vw.setTranslationX(event.getX() - downPos);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                vw.setTranslationX(0);
                break;
        }

        return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

The problem that i have is that the MotionEvents that the listener receives oscilate between two points.

```
D/MyActivity(5098): X: 586.0 
D/MyActivity(5098): X: 585.0 
D/MyActivity(5098): X: 587.0 
D/MyActivity(5098): X: 586.0 
D/MyActivity(5098): X: 589.0 
D/MyActivity(5098): X: 587.0 
D/MyActivity(5098): X: 590.0 
D/MyActivity(5098): X: 588.0 
D/MyActivity(5098): X: 591.0 
D/MyActivity(5098): X: 589.0 
D/MyActivity(5098): X: 592.0
```

Notice how the values go up and down. Since I use it for translating the View I get some kind of flickering.

It is not the first time I notice this. I used a ScaleGestureDetector on an ImageView to scale the image once where I had the same problems.

Does anyone had the same problems and could solve them? Or this a hardware failure?

My device is an acer A500 (Iconia Tablet)

EDIT: I tested it on the emulator. I have the prblem there as well. So it is not the fault of the device but is a bug in the Android SDK or me not understanding MotionEvents right.